Adaptive regret bounds in Online Convex Optimization
I have recently stumbled upon a proof in Elad Hazan's book "Introduction to Online Convex Optimization" with a step I can't quite grasp.

In the second to last line it is not clear to me why $ \sum_{t\in I} f_t(x_t^r) =\text{Regret}_{s-r+1}(\mathcal{A}) $. In particular, why is $-\min_{x\in K}\sum_{t\in I}f_t(x)$ omitted from the left-hand side?
